# Where can I look at the Rails controller high-level superclasses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, inheritance, superclass

I am trying to understand some of the higher level functioning of Rails, using the Rails console. I run `controller.class.superclass.superclass` which gives `ActionController::Base`, `controller.class.superclass.superclass.superclass` which gives `ActionController::Metal` and `controller.class.superclass.superclass.superclass.superclass` gives `AbstractController::Base`.

I have found these in the API documentation.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Base.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html

[can only post two links]

I can add to these simply by declaring the classes again in the console, but is there a way to find the original Ruby code for these and to inspect and edit it in its original file(s)? Just in case I need to know the full contents of these for future.

Comment: with pry or pry-rails, one can also run `show-source ActionController::Base`  as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the Rails source code on Github:

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

`bundle show <gem>`

and that will show you where the gem is on your system.  Editing in those files is not advised unless you know how to re-install gems.